# Positive solution for a system of linear inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, systems-of-equations, linear-programming

**Question**

Let $A=[a_{ij}]$ be $n \times n$ real matrix with the positive diagonal. The question is to find (all) the weakest sufficient conditions on the entries of $A$ such that the system $Ax\gg 0$ has a non-negative solution.

**Note**

I have found the two sufficient conditions, which are:

1. $A$ is the [diagonally dominant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix).
2. There exists at least one column containing all non-negative entries.

These conditions come from the observation that if $(1,\cdots,1)$ or the canonical vector $e_i$ is a solution. I wonder that sufficient conditions are obtained only when we know the exact solutions?

One more thing, I have worked a bit on [Gordan Theorem](http://fourier.dur.ac.uk/stats/courses/MathFinance/Gordan.pdf) or a similar one. I think it's nice but we do not have a non-negative restriction on the solution.

Btw if you have any ideas or any other conditions, there is always an open room for a discussion.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do yo mean by $Ax\gg 0$ that you have a system of $n$ inequations $R_i x >0$ where $R_i$ is the $i$th row of $A$ ?

Comment: @JeanMarie yes, exactly. So all the inequalities are strictly positive.

Comment: If a nonnegative solution $x$ exists, then also a strictly positive solution $x$ exists (because the set of solutions is open). And then you can incorporate the condition $x \gg 0$ by appending an identity matrix at the bottom of $A$. So we may forget about the condition that $x$ is nonnegative. Edit: no, I just saw that $A$ is assumed to be $n \times n$.

Comment: @BartMichels  thanks for your comments. I think the idea of adding Identity matrix is very helpful.